# Getting information inside double quotes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get information inside quotes in node.js

For example:

```js
var information = 'Hello "beautiful and amazing" world.'
```

How can I log the content written inside the of the `" "`?
I want to get this as result: `beautiful and amazing`

Answer (score 3):

Using regex:

```js
var information = 'Hello "beautiful and amazing" world.'
var regex = /".+"/
var match = information.match(regex)
var res = match?.[0].slice(1, match[0].length - 1)
console.log("Result: " + res)
```

This checks for `"` then any text, then another `"`. Then it removes the `"`s